# Generic batch command to access python script in another directory

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have the following .bat script which is located on the Desktop. I have a python script which resides in a folder ("Folder") also on the Desktop. I can run the .bat script if both files are on the same directory but how I can access the python script when it's in "Folder"? I want this to run on other computers so I am trying to avoid defining usernames (eg. `C:\Users\user_name\Desktop`) unless there is a generic way to obtain user names and incorporate that into the .bat file.

The following is the .bat script:

```
@echo off

rem Root OSGEO4W home dir to the following directory
call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat"

echo.
cmd /k python "Script.py" 
@echo on
```

I tried inserting `cd Folder` before `cmd /k python "Script.py` but that only sets the directory and doesn't follow on to run the python script.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Do you need `cmd` at all? I think you can run python directly from the `.bat` file. That might not solve your main question, but it would be a more natural way to execute a Python script from a `.bat` file.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Brilliant, many thanks for that! Although the question is solved, I noted this command down :)

Comment: @FMc - Thank you for your advice, I will definitely try that as I'm guessing it would work with the answer that's already provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call it as python "folder/script.py".

Although it is slightly odd, because your "cd" solution should have worked as well, so there may be something else going on.

Comment: I believe `cmd` is starting a subshell, which might not inherit the current working directory from the parent batch script (I don't have a windows machine available to test at the moment)

Comment: @Vicky - Ah crap I asked a dumb question! Thank you very much, simple answer to an even simpler question!

Comment: @SimonFraser - Thanks for your tip, that makes sense. I will try and test this as I am still on the learning curve :)

Comment: @SimonFraser I'm sure you're right. I didn't even notice the "cmd" in there at the front as I am so used to writing `python foo.py` at the command line or in a batch file.

Comment: @SimonFraser, a child process defaults to inheriting the working directory of the parent. cmd.exe uses the default behavior unless you specify otherwise via the `start` command's `/D` switch. In this case you may also want to reuse the same console window (`/B`) and wait for the program to exit (`/W`).

Comment: Just run `"folder\script.py"`, i.e. specifying `python` *should* be redundant if your system is configured right . On a related note, if you have Python 3.3+ installed, then the .py extension should be associated with the new py.exe launcher. This lets you add `#!python2` and `#!python3` shebangs to the first line of your scripts to run using a particular version, without having to modify file type associations.

Comment: @eryksun - Awesome, thanks for clarifying. I have python 3.2 so will follow your advice as it would be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
start python Folder/Script.py
```

in your bat-file.

It will open a separate command line window and executes the script in that window.

Comment: Thanks rherzog, I am aware of the `start` command but I want it to be executed in the same window (I perhaps should have mentioned it in the question).